# Manage distances and bearings tool in Cogo toolbar is grayed out

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I made a line feature class to draw boundaries of parcels in QGIS. I added a beacon which represent the starting point. Now I want to add distances and azimuths. The only way is to use the manage distances and bearings tool.

[image: greyed out toolbar]

Comment: https://github.com/kartoza/parcel_plugin/blob/master/utilities.py#L79 *Check DB schema for actions availability. eg: **Manage bearing and distance action needs Beacon to be created first.***

Comment: i created the beacon and the tool is still greyed out